# Python Concatenation Error

Tags: python, concatenation

I am learning python and am stuck on a tutorial which as far as the guide goes should be working but isn't, i have seen similar questions asked but cant understand how they apply to the code i am following, the code fails at the end of the last line.

```
import os
import time

source = ["'C:\Users\Administrator\myfile\myfile 1'"]

target_dir = ['C:\Users\Administrator\myfile']

target = target_dir + os.sep + \
        time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

i have tried some methods using .append and also changing the code by adding [] and () to the + '.zip' but all to no avail, so i was hoping someone could explain why its failing and how i correct it.

i am using python 2.7.9 on windows

thanks

Comment: What tutorial are you using?

Comment: Why are `source` and `target_dir` lists?

Comment: i am not to sure only that is how the tutorial was coded, the tutorial is for a backup script, and the tutorial is a byte of python by swaroop

Comment: For future reference, OP seems to specifically be at [section 13.2](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/python/#_the_solution)

Comment: @YK2: If you followed the tutorial to that point and still don't know where this error comes from please go back a few steps. Don't just write a copy of the code, try to understand the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`target_dir` should not be created with brackets.

```
target_dir = 'C:\Users\Administrator\myfile'

target = target_dir + os.sep + \
        time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
```

---

Incidentally, take care with your backslashes, because they are also used to signify special characters in a string. For example, `"c:\new_directory"` would be interpreted as "C colon newline W..." rather than "C colon backslash N W...". In which case you would need to escape the slash yourself with `"c:\\new_directory"`, or use raw strings like `r"c:\new_directory"`, or regular slashes (if your OS allows that as a path separator) like `"c:/new_directory"`

Comment: according to the docs the source needs double quotes if there are spaces in the directory names, but have also tries it with single quotes and still no go

Comment: Better is `target = os.path.join(target_dir, time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip')`

Comment: @YK2, Whether `source` needs double quotes really depends on what you're doing with it. For instance, if you're passing it to a `os.system` call, you probably need it. But it's incorrect to generally say "a Python string always needs double quotes if it contains a space". What documentation are you referring to?

Comment: thanks kevin, your answer seemed to be the one that worked, i can also see what you mean about taking care with backslashes !

Answer (score 4):

You should use  `os.path.join()` so that the correct platform-specific directory separator will always be used

```
import os
import time

source = "C:\Users\Administrator\myfile\myfile 1"

target_dir = "C:\Users\Administrator\myfile"

target = os.path.join(target_dir, time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip')
```

Comment: @YK2 Did your computer explode? Did monkeys fly out of the screen? Did the house melt? What does "This didn't work" mean?

Comment: @YK2 You need to be more specific than that. What did not work exactly?

Answer (score 2):

target_dir is a list, so in your example you need to do:

```
target = target_dir[0] + os.sep + \
        time.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%S') + '.zip'
```

You see that error because you are trying to add a list (target_list) and strings together, apples and oranges.

Comment: @YK2 no idea what that means.

Comment: thanks for your help anyway, one of the other posts solved it